# Why performance degradation if read/write operations are not performed in multiples of the disk’s block size?

Tags: dd, io

In Love's *Linux System Programming*, in CHAPTER 3 Buffered I/O

> Recall from Chapter 1 that the block is an abstraction representing
> the smallest unit of storage on a filesystem. Inside the kernel, all
> **filesystem operations occur in terms of blocks**. Indeed, the block is
> the lingua franca of I/O. Consequently, no I/O operation may execute
> on an amount of data less than the block size or that is not an
> integer multiple of the block size. If you only want to read a byte,
> too bad: you’ll have to read a whole block. Want to write 4.5 blocks
> worth of data? You’ll need to write 5 blocks, which implies reading
> that partial block in its entirety, updating only the half you’ve
> changed, and then writing back the whole block.
>
> You can see where this is leading: partial block operations are
> inefficient. The operating system has to “fix up” your I/O by ensuring
> that everything occurs on block-aligned boundaries and rounding up to
> the next largest block. Unfortunately, this is not how user-space
> applications are generally written. Most applications operate in terms
> of higher-level abstractions, such as fields and strings, whose size
> varies independently of the block size. At its worst, a user-space
> application might read and write but a single byte at a time! That’s a
> lot of waste. Each of those one-byte writes is actually writing a
> whole block.
>
> **User-Buffered I/O**
>
> Programs that have to issue many small I/O requests to regular files often perform user-
> buffered I/O. This refers to buffering done in user space, either manually by the application or transparently in a library, not to buffering done by the kernel. As discussed in
> Chapter 2, for reasons of performance, **the kernel buffers data internally by delaying
> writes, coalescing adjacent I/O requests, and reading ahead**. Through different means,
> user buffering also aims to improve performance.
>
> Consider an example using the user-space program dd:
>
> ```
> dd bs=1 count=2097152 if=/dev/zero of=pirate
> ```
>
> Because of the bs=1 argument, this command will copy two megabytes
> from the device /dev/zero (a virtual device providing an endless
> stream of zeros) to the file pirate in 2,097,152 one-byte chunks. That
> is, it will copy the data via about two million **read and write
> operations**—one byte at a time.
>
> Now consider the same two megabyte copy, but using 1,024 byte blocks:
>
> ```
> dd bs=1024 count=2048 if=/dev/zero of=pirate
> ```
>
> This operation copies the same two megabytes to the same file, yet
> issues 1,024 times fewer **read and write operations**. The performance
> improvement is huge, as you can see in Table 3-1. Here, I’ve recorded
> the time taken (using three different measures) by four dd commands
> that differed only in block size. Real time is the total elapsed wall
> clock time, user time is the time spent executing the program’s code
> in user space, and system time is the time spent executing system
> calls in kernel space on the process’s behalf.
>
> Table 3-1. Effects of block size on performance
>
> ```
> Block size Real time User time System time
>
> 1 byte 18.707 seconds 1.118 seconds 17.549 seconds
> 1,024 bytes 0.025 seconds 0.002 seconds 0.023 seconds
> 1,130 bytes 0.035 seconds 0.002 seconds 0.027 seconds
> ```
>
> Using 1,024 byte chunks results in an enormous performance improvement
> compared to the single byte chunk. However, the table also
> demonstrates that **using a larger block size—which implies even fewer
> system calls—can result in performance degradation if the operations
> are not performed in multiples of the disk’s block size**. **Despite
> requiring fewer calls, the 1,130 byte requests end up generating
> unaligned requests, and are there‐ fore less efficient than the 1,024
> byte requests.**
>
> Taking advantage of this performance boon requires prior knowledge of
> the physical block size. The results in the table show the block size
> is most likely 1,024, an integer multiple of 1,024, or a divisor of
> 1,024. In the case of /dev/zero, the block size is actually 4,096
> bytes.

1. Why is it that "Despite requiring fewer calls, the 1,130 byte
   requests end up generating  unaligned requests, and are therefore
   less efficient than the 1,024  byte requests"? (Why not   the same
   performance as 1024 byte requests?)

   - Is the ratio between `count` and `bs` the number of system calls issued by `dd`?
   - How is the number of "read and write operations" decided?
2. If " the kernel buffers data internally by delaying writes,
   coalescing adjacent I/O requests, and reading ahead", why do we need
   user buffer? Isn't it that kernel buffer already does the  job that
   user buffer does?
3. Does "filesystem operations occur in terms of blocks" mean that an
   operation occurs in terms of a block, or any integer multiple of blocks?

Thanks.

Comment: Answering your question #2 is the whole point of the part that you quoted: Doing I/O byte by byte requires millions of syscalls, which are pretty expensive on their own. Using a larger buffer reduces the number of syscalls.

Answer (score 6):

> Why is it that "Despite requiring fewer calls, the 1,130 byte requests end up generating unaligned requests, and are therefore less efficient than the 1,024 byte requests"?

I'll provide the conceptual model.  The kernel may have some optimizations to make this less of a problem (but not make the problem go away completely).

If the block size is 1024, then you'll have a sequence of blocks:

```
[1, 1024], [1025, 2048], [2049, 3076], [3077, 4096], ...
```

If you write chunks of size 1130, then the first call to the `write()` system call must write two disk blocks to satisfy the one request.  It will first write the the first 1024 bytes to block `[1, 1024]`, leaving 106 bytes unwritten.  Then it will read the second block (`[1025, 2048]`) copy the remaining 106 bytes into the first 106 bytes of that block, then write that block back to disk.

The next call to the `write()` system call must read the second block again (`[1025, 2048]`), copy the first 918 bytes (1024-106) of the 1130 bytes being written to bytes `[1131, 2048]` of that block, then write that block back to disk.  Then it will read the third block (`[2049, 3076]`), write the last 212 bytes of the 1130 to the first 212 bytes of that block, then write that block back to disk.

That pattern continues -- even though there are fewer calls to `write()`, the kernel has to repeatedly read/update/write existing blocks instead of simply writing blocks.

If you align the `write()`s to the block size, then there's none of the "read a block, update a piece of it, write it back", it can just write the block and move on, and you don't have to read/update the same block to satisfy multiple calls to `write()`.

> If " the kernel buffers data internally by delaying writes, coalescing adjacent I/O requests, and reading ahead", why do we need user buffer? Isn't it that kernel buffer already does the job that user buffer does?

The user space does not have direct access to the kernel space buffer.  The user space buffer is necessary to enable program to read "chunks" without having a system call per byte (as Love illustrates is inefficient).

> Does "filesystem operations occur in terms of blocks" mean that an operation occurs in terms of a block, or any integer multiple of blocks?

I think this would depend on the device and the protocol used to communicate with the storage device.

Comment: Thanks. How about the questions that you haven't addresed?